# HaskellでVariable not in scope

Tags: haskell

今日Haskellを始めました。

https://www.haskell.org/platform/ よりインストールを終え、サンプルコードをfile.hsという名前で保存しました。
GHCi画面にてghci file.hsと入力すると、

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main ( file.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main >
```

と出力されなければならないところ

```
Variable not in scope: ghci :: t0 -> b0 -> c
Variable not in scope : file
Variable not in scope : hs :: a -> b0
```

とエラーが出て先に進めません。
ネットで検索してみましたが、わかりません。

どうか助言をお願い致します。

Comment: `file.hs`と言うファイルを読み込むのではなく、`ghci file.hs`という文字列をHaskellプログラムとして実行しようとした状態に見えます。「GHCi画面にて」とありますが、GHCi起動前のターミナルに対して入力しないといけない内容を、GHCi起動後に入力してしまっているのではないですか? 具体的な操作内容(ターミナルを立ち上げるところから)や参考にしたページへのリンクなどを掲載されると、詳しい回答を得やすいでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

おそらく GHCi を起動した後プログラムの入力を待っているところに直接 `ghci file.hs` と打ち込んだのだと思います。

正しくは、

- シェルで GHCi を起動する際のオプションとしてファイル名を指定する。

  ```sh
  $ ghci file.hs
  ```

とするか、

- GHCi を起動したあと、`:load file.hs` とする。

  ```haskell
  Prelude> :load file.hs
  ```

とすれば良いです。